# SharpDx toolkit SwapChainPanel integration

Tags: c#, directx, windows-8.1, directx-11, sharpdx

I am currently working with SharpDx for a project that targets Win 8.1 and requires multiple 3D viewports on a page, along with other xaml elements. I have so far been able to install the SharpDx toolkit via Nuget, and been able to run a standard toolkit project. However the project uses the SwapChainBackgroundPanel control as the method of rendering the 3D content, shown below.

MainPage.xaml

```
<SwapChainBackgroundPanel
    x:Class="MyGame1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyGame1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="1280"
    d:DesignHeight="800">

</SwapChainBackgroundPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage
  {
    private readonly MyGame1 game;

    public MainPage()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      game = new MyGame1();
      this.Loaded += (sender, args) => game.Run(this);
    }
  }
```

According to documentation I read, the SwapChainBackgroundPanel has been deprecated in favour of the newly introduced SwapChainPanel, however when I attempted to replace the SwapChainBackgroundPanel with the SwapChainPanel, I received an error.

Does anyone know if there is a plan in the immediate future to update the SharpDx toolkit to work with the SwapChainPanel in the same manner as it currently does with the SwapChainBackgroundPanel?

Thanks!

Comment: SharpDX is updated almost on a daily basis. You can download the [latest dev build](http://sharpdx.org/upload/SharpDX-SDK-LatestDev.exe)

Anyway, what error did you get? If it is not yet implemented, you can ask on [GitHub](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX).

Answer (score 3):

The DirectX 11.2 build already fully supports integration with `SwapChainPanel`.

I have added a [sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/tree/master_integration/Samples/Toolkit/WinRT/MiniCube.WinRT.SwapChainPanel) that demonstrates this feature.

First, make sure your project references DirectX 11.2 assemblies - this involves project editing, as described [here](http://devplanet.blogspot.com/2014/02/sharpdx-toolkit-tutorial-1-introduction.html).

After this, edit your page xaml as needed, for example like this (some code is omitted for brevity):

```
<Page ...>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <SwapChainPanel x:Name="panel" x:FieldModifier="private" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Then you need to run your game as usual like this:

```
using SharpDX.Toolkit;

public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    private readonly Game _game;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _game = new MiniCubeGame();
        _game.Run(panel);
    }
}
```

You can move the `_game.Run(...)` call to `Loaded` event handler if this fits better your architecture.

Comment: what is the proper way to release game resources? the MiniCubeGame impements IDisposable so it must be called somewhen.